# Iteratively insert rows into a postgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy in python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am writing a script that reads data from excel files and writes into a postgresql database. I have read data from the excel file and stored each row data as an array of strings.

I tried a couple of things, like

```
  for x in range(len(sh.columns)):
        i = users.insert()
        i.execute({sh.columns[x] : sh.values[0][x]})
```

Here is the reference to my Excel sheet and the table I'm editing in the postgreSQL database I referred to by users.

I also tried an

`'INSERT INTO users VALUES %s'%(tuple(sh.values[0])`

and a few more variations of that.

Comment: It would help if you post any error messages that come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. This is what I used and it works like a charm!

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm



sh = pd.ExcelFile("ExcelFileName").parse("SheetName")
db=sql.create_engine('DBtype://username:password@localhost:postnumber/dbname')
metadata = sql.schema.MetaData(bind=db,reflect=True)



table = sql.Table('TableinDB', metadata, autoload=True)

class Row(object):
 pass
rowmapper = orm.Mapper(Row,table)
print table.columns

Sess = orm.sessionmaker(bind = db)
session = Sess()

for x in range(len(sh.values)):
 row1 = Row() 
 row1.field1 = sh.values[x][0]
 row1.field2 = sh.values[x][1]
 #Add as many fields as you want
session.add(row1)
#forloop ends
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you can write to the table, try in more raw way:

```
i.execute( "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) " % (data1, data2, data3) )
```

Modify the above to have appropriate table name, field names and data values.

Once this works, you can refine writing from sh.

Comment: Thanks Avid, That is an easy way to do it. But I have all data stored in an array and I'm trying to automate the script, so that way of doing will have me to hardcode all the column names into the insert line. I also have multiple sheets in the excel file. I did a little more research and was able to get the task done.
I am doing it using sessions and tansactions using ORM. I read about it but was not able to use it correctly. I figured it out and it works like a charm now. Thanks anyways Avid.

Comment: great, can you post snippet of your solution as an answer? You can later accept your own answer. Plus others will be able to learn from your solution.

Comment: There you go! I posted the solution to my answer!