# inserting data to Postgres using SQL alchemy in flask

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am passing from my local machine, a person id and person name to an ubuntu server. then this information will be read and passed to the database. I am using the below code, but somehow I am not able to get it done. I am new to all these, so not sure what I am missing

```
@app.route("/personInformation", methods=['POST'])
def parsingData():

        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        personID = data['person_id']
        personName = data['person_name']

        import pandas as pd
        import sqlalchemy as sql
        import sqlalchemy.orm as orm         

        db=sql.create_engine(connectionString)            
        metadata = sql.schema.MetaData(bind=db,reflect=True)
        table = sql.Table('patient_all_info', metadata, autoload=True)

        class Row(object):
            pass
        rowmapper = orm.Mapper(Row,table)
        Sess = orm.sessionmaker(bind = db)
        session = Sess()
        row1 = Row() 
        row1.person_id = personID
        row1.person_name = personName
        session.add(row1)
        session.commit()
        return "sent, no error"
```

Comment: First of all, get rid of that all-eating `except:`, which is hiding the error, and the rerun your code and post the error *with the traceback*.

Comment: I followed this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181575/iteratively-insert-rows-into-a-postgresql-database-using-sqlalchemy-in-python

Comment: Ah my bad, I missed your `db=sql.create_engine(connectionString)`. So it is not "very wrong" at all. But still, if you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, do follow its tutorials :). The link you provided handles mapping the "old way" among other things, instead of using [Declarative](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/). Flask-SQLAlchemy also provides integration to Flask request life cycle out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

could you give the construct below a try? I adapted it from one of my projects.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(connstring)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()    
conn = engine.connect()    
metadata = MetaData()

SomeDataTable = Table('TableName', metadata,
    Column('Column1', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('Column2', String(250), nullable=False),
    schema = 'schema_name'
)

stmt = SomeDataTable.insert().values([{"Column1": 1},{"Column2": "test"}])
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: I want to do it in flask

Comment: Yes, you can do this in flask. Ideally, you would separate the Table class from your function but basically what your data parsing function needs to do is just to accept the payload, construct the statement and then execute i.e. the last 2 lines in my answer. Flask is just your web microframework and is independent of your db operations. I use flask for my project too.